# elasticsearch search result null

Tags: php, elasticsearch

i need to set a simple condition for elastic search database that if the result is null that it will show that the searched result does not exists.

```
$result = $client->search($params);
```

but in elastic search when the result is even null it returns this ---

```
Array (
    [took] => 1 
    [timed_out] => 
    [_shards] => Array ( 
        [total] => 2 
        [successful] => 2
        [failed] => 0 
    ) 
    [hits] => Array (
        [total] => 0 
        [max_score] => 
        [hits] => Array ( ) 
    )
)
```

So when i set the condition to check whether the result is null or not, it will never going to execute i guess, because of the previous line.

```
if ($result != null ){
    echo ($result); 
} else {
   echo "Your search doesnot exists";
}
```

So how to simply set the condition for elastic-search when the result returns empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
     if ($result['hits']['total'] > 0 ){
                echo ($result); 
            } else {
                echo "Your search doesnot exists";
            }
```

Comment: thanks wolo for your good answer, i voted-up your answer  as well :)

Answer (score 1):

`ElasticSearch` return the actual searched content in the `hits` array.

You can check for `hits['total']` to get the number of items matched your query and all the individual item exits in the `hits['hits']` array.

Comment: thanks Dau for your good answer, i voted-up your answer  as well :)